# How to identify characters in the matched string that corresponded to dot in regex pattern?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have the following dataframe. The column 'regex' shows my regex patterns and the column 'matched_string' contains the strings that are matched with them. What I would like to have, is another column that contains the index of characters within the strings that are specifically matched with the dot in regex pattern

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'pattern_id': ['A_1', 'B_1', 'C_1'], 
'regex': ['[LIVMP].{0,2}(T)P..([ST])', '[AVP].[ST][ST][ST]', '^M{0,1}([ED]).'], 
'matched_string': [ 'PSTPLVT', 'PVTTT', 'MEG']})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The resulting dataframe I am looking for is this:

```
    Name pattern_id regex                    matched_string  char_indexes
0    A        A_1  [LIVMP].{0,2}(T)P..([ST])        PSTPLVT  [1, 4, 5]
1    B        B_1         [AVP].[ST][ST][ST]          PVTTT  [1]
2    C        C_1             ^M{0,1}([ED]).            MEG  [2]
```

I have tried to somehow take advantage of pattern.match() but it only determines if the string is a match to the pattern which I already know is.

Comment: Then you need to capture the dots, and then just get the `.start()` positions of each capturing group.

Comment: Actually, it is not clear why the first string should yield `[1, 4, 5]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the very helpful suggestion, I'll definitely try that.
Because if we break the reg pattern and matched characters the dots represent chars in those indexes in this example. even though it could be different in another possible matchable string for this pattern. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I can only share [this demo](https://ideone.com/jSCLUh) for you. What you need is actually too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the answer that was given in the comments.

You can get the start and end indexes of a match group within a string using Match.start and Match.end.

So if you are able to alter your `regex` field, you can achieve what you want as follows:

```py
import re

matches = re.match(
    "[LIVMP](?P<firstDots>.{0,2})(T)P(?P<secondDots>..)([ST])", "PSTPLVT"
)

print(
    [i for i in range(matches.start("firstDots"), matches.end("firstDots"))]
    + [i for i in range(matches.start("secondDots"), matches.end("secondDots"))]
)

# [1, 4, 5]
```

See Python `re` docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked in the end for different patterns (based on @Arnoux 's answer ):

```
def regex_dot_indexer(reg_pattern, string):
    
    dot_pattern = re.compile(r'\.\{?\d*,?\d*\}?')
    dot_indices = [(m.start(), m.end()) for m in dot_pattern.finditer(reg_pattern)]

    # If there are no dots, return the original reg_pattern
    if not dot_indices:
        return reg_pattern

    # Assign unique names to the dots in the reg_pattern
    given_names = [f'Given_name_{i + 1}' for i in range(len(dot_indices))]

    # Replace each dot with the corresponding "Given_name" pattern
    modified_reg_pattern = ''
    last_end = 0
    for i, (start, end) in enumerate(dot_indices):
        dot_range = reg_pattern[start:end]
        if dot_range.startswith('.'):
            modified_reg_pattern += reg_pattern[last_end:start] + f'(?P<{given_names[i]}>.{dot_range[1:]})'
        last_end = end

    modified_reg_pattern += reg_pattern[last_end:]
    matches = re.match(modified_reg_pattern, string)
    lst = []
    for i in  given_names:
        z = [i for i in range(matches.start(i), matches.end(i))]
        lst.append(z)
    return [item for sublist in lst for item in sublist]
```

example use case:

```
string_a_dot_idx = regex_dot_indexer('[LIVMP].{0,2}(T)P..([ST])', 'PSTPLVT')
# [1, 4, 5]
```